# What is the generalisation of the wave differential equation in curved spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, waves, metric-tensor, differential-equations

Referring to this famous equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation

Comment: What sort of generalization are you looking for? The wave equation as such is just an equation, it doesn't know anything about "spacetime" or "physics" - it only becomes physical in some concrete setting, like the waves of a vibrating string, or electromagnetic waves. Which setting do you have in mind here, and why do you think curved spacetime matters for it (e.g. a vibrating string certainly doesn't really care about curvature of spacetime at scales far larger than it)?

Answer (score 2):

The [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) is
$$\left(\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}
 -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}
 -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}
 -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right) u = 0,$$

or written in covariant form
$$\left(\eta^{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}\right)u=0,$$
where $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is the inverse Minkowski metric.

The operator on the left (before $u$) is the d'Alembert operator,
which is kind of a 4-dimensional [Laplace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator).

The generalization of this to curvilinear coordinates ($\xi^\mu$)
is (according to [Laplace operator - Coordinate expressions - N dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#N_dimensions)):
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{det }g}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi^\mu}
\left(\sqrt{\text{det }g}\ g^{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi^\nu}\right) u = 0$$
where $g^{\mu\nu}$ is the inverse metric
and $\text{det }g$ is the determinant of the metric.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a completely well-posed question because there are some ambiguities in how you generalize a flat-space equation to curved space.

The so-called "minimal coupling" prescription is to replace partial derivatives with covariant derivatives, and instances of the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ with a general spacetime metric $g_{\mu\nu}$.

For example, for a scalar field:

\begin{equation}
\eta^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \partial_\nu \phi + V'(\phi) = 0 \rightarrow g^{\mu\nu} \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu \phi + V'(\phi) = 0
\end{equation}

For $U(1)$ gauge field (electromagntism):

\begin{equation}
\eta^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu F_{\nu\lambda} = 0 \rightarrow g^{\mu\nu} \nabla_\mu F_{\nu\lambda} = 0
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu \rightarrow F_{\mu\nu} = \nabla_\mu A_\nu - \nabla_\nu A_\mu
\end{equation}
(however for a gauge field it actually turns out that because of the antisymmetry in $\mu,\nu$, $\nabla_\mu A_\nu-\nabla_\nu A_\mu=\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$).

...and so on.

This is not the only way to generalize the wave equation from flat space to curved space, because you can always add powers of the Riemann curvature to the equation, which will vanish in Minkowski space. Sometimes it is interesting to add powers of the curvature; for instance the equation of motion for a *conformally coupled* scalar field is

\begin{equation}
g^{\mu\nu} \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu \phi + \frac{1}{6}R \phi = 0
\end{equation}